# JDBC table error : Unknown database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, wamp

I've installed WAMP's mysql server and created the database named `getataxi`. When I go to `phpMyAdmin` i can see the database and its tables. I also connected to this database through JDBC. When i create a connection to the database using :

> conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

**I get this error** :

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'getataxi'
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)

what could be the problem ?

*Note :*

1. My wamp server is online .
2. I tried to connect to a test database that comes with the software, it seems it can find the test database because i get different error message saying the table in database is not found and its true .
3. I tried building getataxi with uppercase letters and lower case but didnt help .
4. I had a *.sql file that contained the tables that i imported .
5. DB_URL is `jdbc:mysql://localhost/getataxi` i also tried `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/getataxi`
6. Mysql USER is root
7. I am using Windows

Comment: Can you access getataxi over the network? If not, is the port open and mysql listening on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following simplified case works fine for me under WAMP ([USBWebserver](http://www.usbwebserver.net)), successfully listing all of the tables in the database named `getataxi`:

```java
import java.sql.*;

public class mysqlTestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            String myConnectionString =
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/getataxi?" +
                    "useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myConnectionString, "root", "beer");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute("SHOW TABLES");
            ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

If the same code does not work for you then try the following code to list all of the (visible) databases on the server:

```java
import java.sql.*;

public class mysqlTestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            String myConnectionString =
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306?" +
                    "useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myConnectionString, "root", "beer");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute("SHOW DATABASES");
            ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

When I run it I get a list like this:

```
information_schema
getataxi
mydb
mysql
performance_schema
test
```

Comment: im so sorry to bother all of with this question it turns out that i forgot that ive installed mysql server a month ago before wamp and its running as a service so when i connect to the database it connects to mysql and not wamp , now i stoped mysql service and it works , again so sorry

Answer (score 0):

MySQL tables and databases correspond to files. So if you are under Linux, they are **case-sensitive** (but are not under Windows).

Answer (score -1):

As you said you have wamp server up:

Save the below code as php file and put this in your www folder and try to access the page

```
<?php
$username = "root";  
$password = "your_password";
$hostname = "localhost:3306"; <==change port if different1

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
?>
```

You should be able to see Connected to MySQL message in your browser to confirm the hostname, username and password combination.

In Java code,

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Java2MySql 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
      String dbName = "demo”
      String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
      String userName = "root"; 
      String password = "mypasswd";
      try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
        conn.close();
        System.out.println("Successfully connected");
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
     }
}
```

You see Successfully connected without any errors. Then you have some problem in your code. Please review your code properly.